# php display results of a COUNT? I think

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to display the username column in the while loop below and also with counting how many hits each user had.

```
 $query = "SELECT company, COUNT(company) FROM tableName GROUP BY company"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 // Print out result
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(company)'] ."
 ". $row['company'] ." hits total so far";
 echo "<br />";

 }
```

[image]

**For example**

```
 There are 3 facebook hits total so far - user1(1 total), user2(1 total), user3(1 total)
 There are 2 google hits total - user1(2 total)
 There are 6 mircosoft hits total - user3(1 total)
 There are 0 dropbox hits total
```

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic data you want comes from:

```
SELECT company, userid, COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY company, userid;
```

An approximation of the format you want is:

```
SELECT company, GROUP_CONCAT(userid, '(', cnt, ' total)')
FROM (SELECT company, userid, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM tableName
      GROUP BY company, userid
     ) cu
GROUP BY company;
```

Of course, this does not have a row for "dropbox".  For that functionality, you need a table with the companies of interest and you need to `LEFT JOIN` it to this query.

As others may note, "mysql" is outdated, you should use mysqli or PDO.